# How to downsize std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Is there a way to resize a `std::vector` to lower capacity when I no longer need previously reserved space?

Comment: Solutions are also found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3477715/5740428

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Effective STL, by Scott Meyers, Item 17: Use the `swap` trick to trim excess capacity.

```
vector<Person>(persons).swap(persons);
```

After that, `persons` is "shrunk to fit".

This relies on the fact that `vector`'s copy constructor allocates only as much as memory as needed for the elements being copied.

Comment: Suggest a fix to the grammar: 'shrunk', not 'shrinked'

Comment: Nice. Do you maybe know why they didn't implement this as a method, as it looks as a common use case for the container?

Comment: Once the vector has allocated a buffer, it's hard to delete[] the end of that buffer. And doing so simply guarantees that future insertions are going to require allocating a new buffer and copying averything to it (invalidating iterators).

Answer (score 20):

If you're using C++11, you can use `vec.shrink_to_fit()`. In VS2010 at least, that does the swap trick for you.

Comment: It's not equivalent to the swap trick. `shrink_to_fit` is a non-binding request and is allowed to not do anything.

Comment: I said "in VS2010" but yeah, on other compilers it may not do it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus `shrink_to_fit` will in all likelihood do the swap trick or `realloc`, but with a small vector optimization that still won't reset `capacity()` to match `size()` because there's no heap allocation to shrink. I think that is the reason it's specified as "non-binding."

Answer (score 8):

Create a new, temporary, vector from the existing one then call the swap method on the existing one, passing the temporary one in. Let the temporary (now with the old, oversized, buffer) go out of scope.

Hey presto, your vector has exactly the right size for its contents.

If this sounds like a lot of copying and allocation - bear in mind that this is what vector does every time it has to realloc past its current reserved limit anyway.

[Edit]
Yes, I just said the same as Sebastien in more words. Another case of stackoverflow race-condition ;-)

Comment: Well, I upvoted you Phil because your answer is still helpful even if you weren't the first one to post it! :-)

Comment: ^ Jeez, tough room. Sebastian beat Phil by _twenty-one whole seconds_, But hey, sure, we'll leave Phil holding some pity upvotes and a second-place . 

Answer (score 3):

The swap trick is an effective way to reduce the capacity of an object, 
it swaps the content of my vector with a newly created one by copy construction:

```
vector<Person>(persons).swap(persons);
```

Notice that there is no guarantee that persons.capacity(); after the swap trick is equal to 
the size: the capacity of vector(persons) is the capacity the library implementation 
reserves to vectors of size persons.size().

C++11 introduced [shrink_to_fit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/).

shrink_to_fit() as well as the swap trick does not guarantee the capacity size is effectively 
reduced to the size of the vector.

Anyway shrink_to_fit() can invalidate your iterators (if a reallocation happens) or cannot: 
it depends on the actual implementation of the library.

Bear in mind that the swap trick requires persons.size() copy constructions of Person and 
person.size() destructions. The shrink_to_fit() could avoid all this copying and could 
leave your iterators valid. Could. But from time to time it happens that shrink_to_fit() is implemented in 
terms of the swap trick...

Comment: Could you please indicate where it's specified that `shrink_to_fit()` must be implemented in terms of `swap()`?

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the remark. Maybe my english is not good enough. I meant that since _shrink_to_fit()_ can be implemented in terms of the swap trick then sometimes it is implemented in this way. Let me edit the answer. If I don't succeed, feel free to edit the answer so to improve its quality. Your contribution would be welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for an equivalent of [QVector::squeeze](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvector.html#squeeze) and I'm afraid it doesn't exist explicitely in the STL. 
Go for Sébastien's answer if it is correct for your STL implementation.