# Why does this C++ function takes 4 time as much as a c function

Tags: c++, c

I am considering using c++ for a performance critical application. I thought both C and C++ will have comparable running times. However i see that the c++ function takes >4 times to run that the comparable C snippet.

When i did a disassemble i saw the end(), ++, != were all implemented as function calls. Is it possible to make them (at least some of them) inline?

Here is the C++ code:

```
typedef struct pfx_s {
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int end;
    unsigned int count;
} pfx_t;

typedef std::list<pfx_t *> pfx_list_t;

int
eval_one_pkt (pfx_list_t *cfg, unsigned int ip_addr)
{
    const_list_iter_t iter;

    for (iter = cfg->begin(); iter != cfg->end(); iter++) {
        if (((*iter)->start <= ip_addr) &&
            ((*iter)->end >= ip_addr)) {
            (*iter)->count++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the equivalent C code:

```
int
eval_one_pkt (cfg_t *cfg, unsigned int ip_addr)
{
    pfx_t *pfx;

    TAILQ_FOREACH (pfx, &cfg->pfx_head, next) {
        if ((pfx->start <= ip_addr) &&
            (pfx->end >= ip_addr)) {
            pfx->count++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on? It should inline them when you turn optimizations on.

Comment: C++ does that to allow for operator overloading. A good optimizer should be able to tell if you're not in fact overloading them and take out the calls.

Comment: The stats that you report seem to imply that you timed debug version of the code, probably with debug version of the library. Such measurements make little or no sense at all.

Comment: The only two areas I see that _might_ benefit from manual optimization is using a local variable to hold the end iterator instead of using `cfg->end()` and changing `iter++` to `++iter`.

Comment: How is the C list implemented?

Comment: actually that is correct. with optimized compiler -O3  on it is close to C (~12% slower than C). Should have thought of it

Comment: It is more than 12%. With C optimized version it took 21 secs whereas the C++ optimized version took 36 secs. The C structure uses the sys/queue.h macros. typedef struct pfx_s {
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int end;
    unsigned int count;
    TAILQ_ENTRY(pfx_s) next;
} pfx_t;

Comment: _"Is it possible to make them (at least some of them) inline?"_ Yes, but if you don't compile with optimisations enabled then they won't be inlined. **DON'T BENCHMARK UNOPTIMIZED CODE.** C++ lets you write at a high level, so if you don't optimise then there is extra overhead, but the beauty of the language is that overhead can often be optimised away entirely. If your application is performance critical you really need to optimise. Really.

Comment: I just so hate these rigged comparisons claiming "equivalent" that are so obviously not. And even more hate performance-related entries with unoptimized builds -- too bad folks on meta considered it a minority problem

Comment: _"I am considering using c++ for a performance critical application."_ But you didn't optimise it, so you're either not qualified to write performance-critical code or must be trolling to wind up the [tag:c++] folks. Not constructive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be worth noting that the data structures you used are not entirely equivalent. Your C list is implemented as a list of immediate elements. Your C++ list is implemented as a *list of pointers* to actual elements. Why did you make your C++ list a list of *pointers*?

This alone will not, of course, cause four-fold difference in performance. However, it could affect the code's performance do to its worse memory locality.

I would guess that you timed debug version of your code, maybe even compiled with debug version of the library.

Comment: "When i did a disassemble i saw the end(), ++, != were all implemented as function calls." - I think that counts even more.

Comment: yes. with 1) compiler optimization turned on and 2) making the C list a pointer to the structure the performance is pretty close 34.5 for C vs 35.8 for C++

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't be surprised to see that the cache unfriendliness of a list of pointers caused four-fold differences in performance. Furthermore, given that pfx_s is only 3 integers long, it'd be also interesting to see what happens (for good or bad) with a substantially bigger struct; say, as big as a cache line, or more.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a *really* good reason to use a list here at all? At first glance, it looks like a `std::vector` will be a better choice. You probably also don't want a container of pointers, just a container of objects.

You can also do the job quite a bit more neatly a standard algorithm:

```
typedef std::vector<pfx_t> pfx_list_t;

int
eval_one_pkt(pfx_list_t const &cfg, unsigned int ip_addr) {
    auto pos = std::find_if(cfg.begin(), cfg.end(),
        [ip_addr](pfx_t const &p) {
            return ip_addr >= p.begin && ip_addr <= p.end;
        });

    if (pos != cfg.end()) {
       ++(pos->count);
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I were doing it, however, I'd probably turn that into generic algorithm instead:

```
template <class InIter>
int
eval_one_pkt(InIter b, InIter e, unsigned int ip_addr) {
    auto pos = std::find_if(b, e,
        [ip_addr](pfx_t const &p) {
            return ip_addr >= p.begin && ip_addr <= p.end;
        });

    if (pos != cfg.end()) {
       ++(pos->count);
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though unrelated to C vs. C++, for a possible slight further optimization on the range check you might want to try something like this:

```
return ((unsigned)(ip_addr-p.begin) <= (p.end-p.begin));
```

With a modern compiler with optimization enabled, I'd expect the template to be expanded inline entirely at the point of use, so there probably wouldn't be any function calls involved at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. list is a better choice because pfx_ts can come and go. I used object pointer because object can be in multiple lists

Comment: @helloworld: [list still probably isn't a better choice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9765090/179910). Fair enough about using a pointer.

Comment: thanks for the pointer on list vs vectors.yes i agree with your reasoning

Answer (score 4):

I copied your code and ran timings of 10,000 failed (thus complete) searches of 10,000 element lists:

Without optimization:

- `TAILQ_FOREACH` 0.717s
- `std::list<pfx_t *>` 2.397s
- `std::list<pfx_t>` 1.98s

(Note that I put a `next` into `pfx_t` for `TAILQ` and used the same redundant structure with `std::list`)

You can see that lists of pointers is worse than lists of objects.  Now with optimization:

- `TAILQ_FOREACH` 0.467s
- `std::list<pfx_t *>` 0.553s
- `std::list<pfx_t>` 0.345s

So as everyone pointed out, optimization is the dominant term in a tight inner loop using collection types.  Even the slowest variation is faster than the fastest unoptimized version.  Perhaps more surprising is that the winner changes -- this is likely due to the compiler better recognizing optimization opportunities in the `std` code than in an OS-provided macro.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. lists of object doesn't quite work in cases where the object needs to be in more than one list.