# How to get a certain element from multiple inputs C++

Tags: c++

I want to get a certain element based on what the user inputs in different lines. I am new to C++ programming so I am unsure of what route to take.

```
std::string siblings;
std::string names;

std::cout << "Please enter how many siblings you have: ";
std::cin >> siblings;

for (int x=0;x<siblings;x++){
    std::cout << "Please enter your sibling(s) name: ";
    std::cin >> names;
}
```

So if the user entered '3' siblings and typed in Mark, John, Susan, how do i get the name of the 2nd sibling - "John"? Or perhaps the first name entered, or last?

**Also, I wanted the question to just ask once and wait for the user to put in X amount of siblings based on what they put on different lines, then continue onto the program, but the question is repeatedly asking.

Comment: How is `names` declared?

Comment: Do you know about `Array` ?

Comment: @VedantTerkar, I don't. What's `Array`?

Comment: how do i store the values into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should define `siblings` as an `int` rather than an `std::string`, otherwise your use of `operator<` in the `for` loop, won't work. Second, you should use an `std::vector` and push the names inside the `for` loop. Here's the complete working code:

```
int siblings = 0;
std::vector<std::string> names;

std::cout << "Please enter how many siblings you have: ";
std::cin >> siblings;

for (int x = 0; x < siblings; x++) {
    std::string current;
    std::cout << "Please enter the name for sibling #" << (x + 1) << ':';
    std::cin >> current;
    names.emplace_back(current);
}
```

The above code will ask the number of siblings and then will ask for each sibling the name and push it into `names`.

If you really want to adventure yourself into the magic world of string formatting with C and C++, [take a look at this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c).

Comment: What is the difference between a list vs vector? Why can't I use a list?

Comment: @Lalala, Please, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl).