# When should a std::vector be used over a std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Two STL containers, `std::vector` and `std::list`, seem to provide very similar functions. As far as I can tell, the only difference is that a `std::list` provides O(1) time for modification, and O(n) time for reading, and vice-versa for the vector. Ignoring efficiency, are there any other differences? The proposed duplicate seems to focus on efficiency, whereas I am wondering about how the memory differences manifest in semantics differences (such as std::list's splicing capability)?

Comment: Left for Bjarne Stroustrup, [almost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) every time. Quips aside. This is a very broad question.

Comment: Why? I know that the memory structure is different, but why are the semantics different?

Comment: Google will yield the answers you are looking for. It has to do with speed of random acess and insertion of elements within the container http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl almighty Google

Comment: Almost never use `std::list`. One can splice in a part in a list, but as I recall that was made O(n) in order to get the size operation down to O(1), in C++11. Andrew Koenig started on an interesting example in DDJ, about how linked lists could be at least pretty dang convenient in some concrete examples, but it turned out that `std::vector` could provide the same convenience and performance.

Comment: There are two main problems with `std::vector`, namely the specialization for `bool` item type (getting proxy objects rather than real references out of the iterators), and that the standard library lacks a cursor gap wrapper à la queue and stack. But neither problem is solved with `std::list'`.

Comment: Thanks, @Alf. Helpful answers. You should post them in an answer.

Comment: you should actually prefer vector over list in majority of cases https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List has a (much) bigger memory footprint per element, and less cache coherency (even when ignoring the larger element size) than a vector does. This means that it will rely much more on your cache line fetches & memory read speed, which typically is your performance bottleneck, rather than the assumed "read/write for one element" that was used for list/vector's comparison originally.

As a pathological example, consider a vector of 16 `int` versus a list of 16 `int`. The first has a single cache line with 16 ints in it and can do any operation in 1 cache line fetch, where the second has:

- One memory allocation block overhead (16 bytes)
- One pointer to the previous block (8 bytes)
- One pointer to the next block (8 bytes)
- One int (4 bytes)

in every allocated unit. Using the guesstimated sizes above, this puts it at about 36 bytes, rounded up to 40 (because of alignment reasons) and probably to 48 (because of malloc's internal alignment reasons). That would, in the ideal case, load 12 full cache lines, and in the worst case 32 cache lines.

Given that your performance bottleneck is the cache, having everything in 1 or maybe 2 cache lines instead of 12-32 *way* trumps list's theoretical advantages.

Comment: I agree with most here, but what exactly are " list's theoretical advantages"`?

Comment: A list can be split and/or joined efficiently (by virtue of it being discontinuous segments to start with); a list supports O(1) insertion/deletion in the middle. This only actually helps if you already know the locations, because iteration is O(n) in cache lines, where a vector is O(n/(sizeof(cacheline)/sizeof(item))) - strictly still O(n) but usually much less.

Comment: O(1) time for modification, theoretically.

Comment: @dascandy: As far as I can see with `std::list` those operations are decidedly inefficient, O(n), with `std::list`, except insertion/removal of single item, which can be better done with O(1) complexity for cursor gap wrapper of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what I have seen in the comments and answers so far, here are the pros/cons of `list`s over `vector`s:

- Much worse performance in almost all areas
- Splicing capabilities that `vector` does not support
- Less cache coherency, meaning more reliance on memory reading
- Larger item size in list.
- Issues with both `vector` and `list` with bools and wrappers
  Thanks so much for all the help!