# Abstract and Derived combined with std::list

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to wrap my head around how I would go about implementing the following problem:

I have a parent class called `Parent` and many different children classes called `Child1, Child2, etc`.
Now what I ultimately want to be able to do is have a `std::list` or some kind of container to save and access a bunch of different children objects and their derived functions

### for example:

**Parent.h**

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent();

    virtual void logic() = 0;

    //strings and other members of every Child
}
```

**Child1.h**

```
class Child1 : public Gate
{
public:
    Child1 ();
    ~Child1 ();
    void logic();
};
```

**Child1.cpp**

```
void Child1::logic()
{ //Do Stuff }
```

Now let's say I want to have a `std::list` or whatever container is best for  my Abstract class Parents

**main.cpp**

```
std::list <Parent> foo;
```

how would I go about filling the list up with Children of different types and how would I go about iterating over this list and calling each Child's `logic()` function?

I read tons of posts about using `unique_ptr`, using `dynamic cast` or using a `vector` instead of a list but at this point, I'm just more confused than I was before.

Answer (score 2):

Start off by using `std::unique_ptr<Parent>` instead of `Parent` or you'll suffer from [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Next up, it's just a matter of filling up the container with objects and calling their `logic()`, for example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> objects;
objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Child1>());
objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Child2>());
objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Child3>());

for(const auto& child : objects)
  child->logic();
```

The same can of course be done for a `std::list` but prefer `std::vector` here.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() {}

    virtual void logic() = 0;

    //strings and other members of every Child
};

class Child1 : public Parent
{
public:
    void logic() override { std::cout << "Hi from Child1." << std::endl; }
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
    void logic() override { std::cout << "Hi from Child2." << std::endl; }
};

class Child3 : public Parent
{
public:
    void logic() override { std::cout << "Hi from Child3." << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> objects;
    objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Child1>());
    objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Child2>());
    objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Child3>());

    for(const auto& child : objects)
      child->logic();
    return 0;
}
```

[Working example](https://ideone.com/gIAnOi).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you used std::vector instead of a list? Also would this method work with a QList aswell? I heard QLists dont like Abstract Classes

Comment: @Not_very_good Who told you that? AFAIK they work fine. As for std::list vs std::vector read this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl , the second answer specifically.

Comment: @Not_very_good The choice of container depends on how you will use the container and the objects in it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick answers!

Comment: I'm also trying to implement a Map <String, Parent*> that has the name of the child as the key and points to a specific child in the List from earlier . Would adjusting it to be a 
Map <String , std::unique_ptr<Parent>>  be the way to adjust it to your answer? Sorry for the stupid questions, haven't used unique_ptr s much

Comment: Actually i think i confused myself with that last comment:

if i have a 
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>>  
and then i'd use a 
Map <String , std::unique_ptr<Parent>>
and assign specific Child objects from the Vector to specific keys in the map, wouldn't i have 2 pointers to the same Object? Isn't the point of unique_ptrs that that can't happen? Can i generally only have 1 pointer to any of the Objects in my Vector or can i still have tons of other objects pointing at that specific child in the vector?

Comment: So should i use shared_ptr instead if i want both the Vector and the Map to hold pointers to the same specific instances of Child Objects?

Comment: I would make destructor of the grand base virtual, in case reference semantics were intended. Pointers - smart or not - may choose to pick pointee's destructor from their static type. Making the base destructor virtual forces late binding of destructor and safegaurds against slicing at destruction.