# Store input values into array while reading them in, c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am pretty new to c++. I am trying to read a file in line by line and store the input into several arrays.
Because I don't know the size of input file, I have this to get the number of lines in the file

```
while (std::getline(inputFile, line)){
    ++numOfLines; 
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Now I want to use the numOfLines as the size of arrays, but i cannot get it run by having this

```
std::string *firstName= new std::string[numOfLines];
std::string *lastName= new std::string[numOfLines];

for (int i = 0; i < numOfLines; ++i)
{      
    line >> firstName[i];
}
```

I guess it is because it has reached the end of the file after the while loop. But I do not know how to solve this problem. Is there a way to scan the input file in and store the value into array at the same time?

Comment: Your problem is using an array in the first place - use a std::vector and put the strings into the vector in a single pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use std::vector you don't need to know ahead the lines count. You can use vector method push_back to insert new elements into it. Try use something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> first_names;
    std::string line;
    ifstream input_file;

    while (std::getline(input_file, line)){
        first_names.push_back(line);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < first_names.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << first_names[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have ever taken a course related to ***Data Structures & Algorithms***,
in which you will learn to use [*Containers*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (such as:
[`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector),
[`deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque),
[`list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), etc.) instead of *Primitive Data Structures*.

Please notice that although the follow example chooses `vector` as its container, it could vary according to different contexts. Say you are handling gigantic mount of data, you might want to use `list` instead`[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl),[2](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181693/what-are-the-complexity-guarantees-of-the-standard-containers).

```c++
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// alias long type
// @see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias
using NameVector = std::vector<std::string>;

int handleLine(std::string line, NameVector &firstNames)
{
    // TODO implement your line handler here
    firstNames.push_back(line);

    return 0;
}

int handleFile(std::ifstream inputFile, NameVector &firstNames)
{
    std::string line;

    for (int lineNum = 1;

        // invoke `good` to check if there is any error
        inputFile.good()
        &&
        std::getline(inputFile, line);

        lineNum++)
    {
        std::cout << "Current line number : (" << lineNum << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Current line content: (" << line << ")" << std::endl;

        handleLine(line, &firstNames);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::string path;                           // = R"(HERE GOES YOUR FILE PATH)";
                                                // Using **Raw string**
    std::ifstream inputFile { path };           // Initialize `inputFile`
    NameVector firstNames;

    handleFile(inputFile, firstNames);

    for (auto firstName : firstNames)
    {
        std::cout << firstName << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```