# Find common values in map

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Is there a way to find out if a map contains common values?

```
1 : 2
2 : 5
3 : 2
4 : 6
5 : 2
```

above keys 1, 3 and 5 have common values.

I am trying not to use a loop if possible.

I looked at the map key compare and value compare functions but not sure if that’s achieves what I am trying to do.

Edit:
Im interested in seeing if there are any member functions of map or any other functions I can use.

Comment: Do you only want to know IF it contains duplicate values (vs knowing WHAT those duplicates are)? If so, and memory isn't a constraint, you can store all the values in a `set`. Then if the size of the `map` differs from the `set`, you have duplicates.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this but wondering if there is an alternative. And yes I just want to know if it contains duplicates

Comment: Please edit the question to include all methods you are aware of that you don't want to use.

Comment: `std::map<int,std::list<int>>` put the value as key and key as list of value. There is no method which compare value of maps

Comment: Do you need a generic solution or just one that works for specific integer values? Also how big is the data?

Comment: @Mannoj It sounds like a very bad alternative to `std::multimap<int, int>`.

Comment: @Mannoj if I do this, won’t i have to iterate through the list?

Comment: @henhen How is that map populated?  Maybe during the population of that map, you track whether a duplicate occurs?

Comment: @henhen There is no solution that won't require you to iterate through the map. Whether it's to sort it or to check a predicate, whether is hidden in an algorithm function or through recursion, somewhere somehow you will loop.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you don't want to use a loop? Do you mean you don't want the solution to use a loop at all (even under the hood, because of performance reasons), or that you don't want to have a visible loop in your code?

Comment: @Sopel an optimized solution would be great. Data can be any given input.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie map is populated by iterating through a vector.

Comment: @John yes i don’t want to use my own loop.

Comment: @henhen but it's fine if the underlying function loops?

Comment: @John yes map member functions are fine

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's not the same, he can return the duplicate value list in single lookup, which is not possible as u mentioned for multi_map

Comment: Your requirement is strange to me. You could probably attract higher quality answers if you can explain why you're okay with an under-the-hood loop, so long as your part of the code doesn't have a loop in it.

Comment: @henhen what is actual problem? Vector you had, then why map comes here? Explain the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @Mannoj Technically true, but you still have to iterate over the list you obtain so there is no actual gain. Edit : I now see that you don't actually need to iterate over the list in this scenario, you probably only care about the size.

Comment: Yes, iteration must

Answer (score 2):

suppose initial map is m:

```
1 : 2
2 : 5
3 : 2
4 : 6
5 : 2
```

//to create new map

```
map<int , vector<int>> m2;
for(auto it: m)
{
   m2[it.second].push_back(it.first);
}
```

// this will create a map as required, i.e.,

```
2 : [1,3,5]
5 : [2]
6 : [4]
```

//to print or use the new map

```
for(auto it: m2)
{
   cout<<it.first<<": "<<endl;
   for(auto it1 : it.second)
   {
       cout<<it1<<" ";
   }
       cout<<endl;
 }
```

// this will generate an output like:

```
 2 : 1 3 5
 5 : 2
 6 : 4
```

Comment: This is called inverse index. You basically implemented elastic search.

Comment: i thought it may help!

Comment: I think that is a good alternative but the first @John comment is optimal in space allocation.

Comment: Using vector is bad idea, that's why I have mentioned my answer to use list

Comment: what is the benefit of a list over vector?

Comment: @NawedDiwan Memory allocation overhead is there in vector due to resizing. Refer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl

Answer (score 1):

The *values* in the map are just an unordered sequence. To find duplicates you need to organise the values in another container in such a way that allows you to find duplicate easily, for example, copy the values (or pointers to values if the values aren't cheap to copy) into an array and sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no member function of std::map, which can return duplicate based on values.

More details:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Other way you have to iterate the map atleast once as I mentioned in comments.
Fill the `std::map<int,std::list<int>>`.