# How to use lower_bound on a vector of a struct?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, lower-bound

I am trying to use lower_bound on a vector of a struct.

```
struct order_book
{
    string action;
    long order_id;
    string side;
    long quantity;
    long price;
};

vector<order_book> buy_side;
vector<order_book> sell_side;
```

I am not sure how to construct the comparison function. I want to compare "price". I have seen examples where integers from an array were used. It is very straightforward. However, I am confused here as to how should I set my comp function.

Would this work?

```
bool compf(order_book &a, order_book &b){
return a.price< b.price;
}
```

part of code where I have used the lower_bound:

```
//we pass a "temp" vector to this function.
 auto loc=lower_bound(buy_side.begin(),buy_side.end(),stoi(temp.at(4))); 
//stoi(temp.at(4)) is the price of a new order which we want to compare.

if(buy_side.empty() == 0){
buy_side.push_back(order_book{temp.at(0),stoi(temp.at(1)),temp.at(2),stoi(temp.at(3)),stoi(temp.at(4))});
}
else{
buy_side.insert(loc,order_book{temp.at(0),stoi(temp.at(1)),temp.at(2),stoi(temp.at(3)),stoi(temp.at(4))}//, compf(?));
}
```

Comment: From [this `std::lower_bound` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) it can be read that there's an overload taking a fourth argument, being a pointer to the compare function. And that the second argument to the compare function is the *value* to compare with (the one passed to the `std::lower_bound` function as the third argument).

Comment: To use `lower_bound` this way, you need something like `bool price_comp(const order_book& order, long price) { return order.price < price; }`, and then you do `std::lower_bound(buy_side.begin(),buy_side.end(), price_to_find, price_comp)`. Note that the vector must be sorted by `price`.

Comment: 1)Why is it that the vector must be sorted by price?

2) I am trying to populate the vector in a sorted manner. When the new element is populated in vector, we will use the lower_bound method to find the location, and then we will insert it. Thanks for your comment @IgorTandetnik So when new element is added, the vector will be already sorted.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ah. sorry. corrected the mistake. thanks.

Comment: Just a hint, if you've got a very large number of books then using std::list may be more efficient for inserting the books. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl)

Comment: How can we check the value of the element that the iterator points to? Here I would like to check if the price of the element to which iterator returned from the lower_bound method points is equal to the price that we are searching. If the price is same then we will insert that new element behind current one.

Comment: Have you ever looped over a container (like a vector) using iterator? You access the object "pointed to" by the iterator returned by `std::lower_bound` like that loop-iterator: By dereferencing it, or using the `->` access operator. And both vectors and lists have an "insert after this iterator" function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a comparator function as the fourth argument to the lower_bound function (as suggested by some comments above). Third argument will be the value you want to compare (in this case price)

This comparator function should have two parameters. One is of type of the struct you have defined and other one would be of type of the value you want to compare (here that is price).

So the comparator function can be written as:

```
 bool compf(order_book a, long price ){ return a.price< price; }
```

And the lower_bound function can be called as

```
 auto loc = lower_bound(buy_side.begin(),buy_side.end(),price_to_compare, compf);
```

This would work out fine if the vector buy_side is sorted according to price which is required for lower_bound.