# What does clearing and then swapping a std::vector with a copy of itself do?

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
std::vector<weight> decoy;
    
void clear_decoy() {  
    decoy.clear();
    std::vector<weight>(decoy).swap(decoy);  
}
```

In the above method `clear_decoy()`, what does `vector<weight>(decoy).swap(decoy);` mean please?

Does the method clear `decoy` or not? Thanks!

Comment: Remember to accept answers you feel are best by clicking the checkmark by them

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It creates a new vector of `Weight` objects (which will be empty) and swaps it with `decoy`.

The reason for this is that by default, `std::vector<t>::clear` often doesn't actually reduce the storage used by a vector, it merely destroys all the objects contained there. This way, the vector has room to store more objects without reallocation in the future.

Sometimes, however, you want to trim the capacity in the vector. Swapping with a newly created vector (which lives until the end of it's line, and is therefore destroyed there) frees all the memory allocated by the vector.

Comment: Oh dear! My darling C++, you make trouble for those who love you by being smarter than we are.

Comment: Being smart have a social cost.

Comment: This is very C++y. C++ exposes memory management here so you have the chance to customize things for your needs. By default C++ tries to be as fast as it can, and so if you don't follow this code you're going to get faster code. In cases where you have a very large vector and you remove many of its elements then you can use this idiom to free resources to the OS, on the expense of speed. Usually you don't want to do that (i.e., don't fix what's not broken).

Answer (score 23):

I've never seen that form before.

I have seen it written as:

```
vector<weight>().swap(decoy);
```

Which means "create a new empty vector, and swap it with the existing one.

`vector<weight> (decoy).swap(decoy);`

To understand that, break in to parts.

`vector<weight>(decoy)`  create a new vector (with it's contents copied from the now empty decoy).  The new vector is an anonomous temporary, so let's pretent it's name is `newvector`.

`newVector.swap(decoy);`  swaps the new vector with decopy.

(Updated per comments to fix bug)

Comment: +1 for suggesting a better (and more) common construction of the same thing.

Comment: That has to be `vector<weight>().swap(decoy)`. You can call member functions on temporaries, but you can't pass them as non-const reference arguments.

Comment: I think C++0x STL definition adds a `shrink` method to reduce the memory footprint based on the actual size... or is this wishful thinking ?

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, it's called `shrink_to_fit`, but the implementation doesn't have to honour it.

Comment: Well, the implementation doesn't have to reduce the capacity to 0 even for an empty vector either. They could even apply the small string optimization to the vector class too, I just thought worth mentioning it :)

Answer (score 11):

That code is a failed attempt to use a common trick to ensure the memory allocated by the vector is freed. It may or may not actually do that, depending on whether or not the vector's copy constructor allocates memory to match the other vector's size, or its capacity.

To reliably free the memory, use the following:

```
void clear_decoy() {  
    vector<weight>().swap(decoy);  
}
```

This creates a temporary empty vector (with little or no memory allocated), swaps this with `decoy` so that the memory is now owned by the temporary, then destroys the temporary, freeing the memory.

Comment: While this is true, no sane STL implementation is going to allocate based on capacity here.

Comment: @Billy: Indeed; the clumsy clear-copy-swap dance is very likely to work, but the simpler version is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 6):

`clear` removes all entries from the vector, but may not necessarily deallocate the space.  This swap idiom restores the vector to having no space allocated.

Comment: Actually `clear` *can* deallocate the space the vector occupies. But it does not *have* to. It usually does not in most STL implementations though.

Answer (score 3):

As 0A0D mentions, the effect of `swap` is to exchange the underlying controlled memory between the two vectors.  But this warrants a little more explanation.

When you `clear` a `vector`, the elements are removed from it at least as far as the programmer is concerned.  `size()` becomes zero and `capacity()` may or may not change.  But the Standard doesn't guarantee that the memory used by the vector will actually be returned back to the operating system.  So if you had 1000 elements in the vector before the `clear()` and each took 1000 bytes memory, after the `clear()` each element's destructor is called, but the vector may still be holding on to a 1,000,000 byte allocation.

This is sometimes undesirable.  The 'swap trick' you note above has the effect of exchanging the controlled memory between the two vectors.  Hence `decoy` ends up with it's controlled memory reset.

Here is what is happening step-by-step:

1. `decoy` elements are each `erased`. 
   The elements' destructors are
   called, and the vector's `size()`
   becomes zero.  The actual memory may
   not be deallocated.
2. A new vector is constructed on the stack (`vector<weight> (decoy)`) and the elements from `decoy` are copied in to it.  Since `decoy` was just `clear()`ed, no elements are copied in to the temporary vector.  However, see edit below.  You don't know that the controlled memory is not swapped.
3. The temporary vector's and `decoy`'s memory are swapped (`.swap(decoy);`) resulting in `decoy` being both cleared and it's memory transferred to the temporary.
4. The temporary falls off the stack, resulting in it's memory being deallocated.

This is referred to as "[the swap trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector)".

EDIT: As Mike mentions, the original programmer is doing it wrong.  The temporary should not be constructed based on `decoy`, it should just be default constructed.  You don't know for sure that `swap()` will only copy the elements and not the controlled memory underneath.

Answer (score 1):

With clear,

> All the elements of the vector are
>   dropped: their destructors are called,
>   and then they are removed from the
>   vector container, leaving the
>   container with a size of 0.

Swap just swaps the two vectors,

> Swap content
>
> Exchanges the content of the vector by
>   the content of vec, which is another
>   vector of the same type. Sizes may
>   differ.
>
> After the call to this member
>   function, the elements in this
>   container are those which were in vec
>   before the call, and the elements of
>   vec are those which were in this. All
>   iterators, references and pointers
>   remain valid for the swapped vectors.

It seems you are swapping nothing really and just restores to default allocation. Clear can deallocate but it sometimes does not. You are not only reducing the size but lessening the space allocated with the swap statement.

Comment: @ladyfafa: With the swap statement, the amount of space allocated is reduced. That is the nice part of vectors.