# How can I recover the memory from a std::vector?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to downsize std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector)
>   [C++ vector::clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477715/c-vectorclear)

When I call `vector<double>::clear()` on some vectors with large sizes, I do not see the memory returned to the system in Task Manager / Performance.

Apparently this is because the container [expects you will use that same memory again](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/9614/).  I am not going to use that memory again, once the task is done, and the memory would be better returned to the system.

Is there a way to ensure the memory returns to the system immediately, *other than* using a pointer like `vector<double> * v` / calling `delete` on `v` when we want the memory returned to the system?

Comment: Already asked [C++ vector::clear][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477715/c-vectorclear

Comment: You really shouldn't use Task Manager for this.

Comment: Pretty much anything that people answer to this will only get as far as the `vector` freeing its memory back to the memory allocator. The criteria that your standard library and OS use for when to free unallocated memory from the process back to the system are another matter entirely, so even once it's working you won't necessarily be able to see it in Task Manager.

Comment: Hey, closers, did you know that the answer provided here is better than in the linked question?

Comment: @bobobobo Instruments, DTrace and valgrind.

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually _yes_ the Task Manager is doing _precisely_ what I want. Tell me how much system memory is being used, and whether my process is hogging the machine's available memory or not (or whether that memory is now available to other applications).

Comment: @bobobobo: If you suspect the answer(s) here to be better, I suggest that you propose in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) to merge this into the other question. If the users there agree, it can be flagged for merging. (In fact, if you get enough support, you might even be able to reopen this and close the others as a dupe of this one.)

Comment: @bobobobo: fair enough, just bear in mind that it is not necessarily possible to recover the memory from a vector. If `shrink_to_fit()` doesn't return the memory to the system then it's not because the container expects you to use it again, it's because the implementation (or OS) does, and has nothing to do with the fact that the memory happened to be used in a vector. For a large enough allocation you'd hope that the memory came "direct" from the OS, and can be returned direct to the OS, but it doesn't always work like that, and almost certainly will not for smaller allocations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 introduced `shrink_to_fit` method that should do it (note that it's not strictly *guaranteed* to work, but it's very likely it will):

```c
your_vector.clear();
your_vector.shrink_to_fit();
```

If you can't use C++11 features, then you can use following trick, which will clear your vector and deallocate all the memory it uses:

```c
std::vector<double>().swap(your_vector);
```

That said, it's possible that, even though the vector will free whatever memory it allocated, the allocator won't give the memory back to the operating system. But at least this memory will be available for other parts of your application.

Comment: grr.. (standing for 'grrreat answer!')

Comment: Actually, according to [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/620047-resize-clear-vector), if you put scope blocks around the temporary, it should actually clear the memory

Answer (score 2):

You could use the swap trick to do this:

```
vector<double>().swap(v);
```

This creates a new empty vector, then swaps it's contents with v.  v will then be empty, and the memory it used to own will be released.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your vector inside a block, like this

```
...//your code
{
    vector<double> v(10);
    //use it
}
...//your other code
```

In this way your vector "v" will be destroyed and the memory will be released automatically at the end of the scope (after the closing `}`).

Comment: No-can-do sir.. the vector's a member of an object