# Proper way to delete and free up memory of a vector (prevent different memory related errors) in c++

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

creating a vector:

```
std::vector<int> pqrs;
```

delete in proper way to free up all memory (prevent memory leaks and other memory related issues) inside the function:

```
pqrs.clear();
std::vector<int>().swap(pqrs);
```

My question is: both clear and swap required (say for calling destructor)? or swap is sufficient for all purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ vector::clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477715/c-vectorclear)

Comment: You don't need either. The vector clears up when going out of scope.

Comment: Do you mean to clear the memory inside a function, or when it goes out of scope? The latter is done automatically anyway.

Comment: Of course inside the function. "latter is done automatically anyway."-yup, I know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phrase about memory leaks makes the whole meaning of the question unclear.  When the vector goes out of scope, the memory is released.  There should be no memory leak.

In major projects, it is fairly common to need a vector to release its allocation at a certain point **before** it goes out of scope.  Failure to do so is not a memory leak but may be a problem. For that purpose, `.clear()` is useless.  The `swap` approach you suggested (without the `.clear`) works.  I don't know a way to do it without `swap`.

Comment: what if it is `std::vector<strucType> pqrs;` ?

Comment: The destructor of the `vector` calls the destructor of the objects it holds, so memory they might own is not leaked.  The only benefit of that `swap` trick is the vector's allocation can be released prior to its end of scope.  If the vector is going out of scope anyway, that takes care of all the required destruction and memory release.

Answer (score 2):

In case of `std::vector<int>` you don't need to do either `clear()` nor `swap` to free memory, because elements of `std::vector<int>` here (`int`s) are automtically allocated and freed by the `std::vector<int>` methods anddestructor. Data will be freed at the end of scope (function or program).

Hence,answer to your question would be, You don't need to call `clear` or `swap`.

Comment: I know but, from the `std::vector<int>` user point of view, we can say they are. I said that to avoid to complicate things :)

Comment: Unfortunately that makes your answer sound wrong. It is quite misleading.

Comment: actually, I want to know complicate things, I just asked in simple form @Pierre

Comment: Thanks, that's better.

Comment: what if it is `std::vector<strucType> pqrs;` ?

Comment: it depends on how you structType has been created:
- if you write : `structType* obj = new structType; pqrs.push_back(*obj);` you need to `delete` manually `obj` because a copy has been created each time you `push_back`;
- if you write : `structType obj; pqrs.push_back(obj);` you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since `vector<int>` object in above question is a variable with `automatic` storage - so it will be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. And when a container object goes out of scope, it's destructor is called which in-turn frees up space used for storage of contained elements and during this step destructor for all contained elements also gets invoked (in case of user-defined types). So, if we have just plan `int` elements, no need to do anything extra. But we would have memory leak if contained type if `T*` where `T` is some user-defined type because in that case destructor wouldn't be called explicitly for pointed-to objects.

Comment: @juanchopanza I edited my answer. I meant that vector object doesn't contain any pointers but wrote it in wrong way. I hope after edit, my answer is at-least not contain any wrong information