# Removing item from vector while iterating?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a vector that holds items that are either active or inactive. I want the size of this vector to stay small for performance issues, so I want items that have been marked inactive to be erased from the vector. I tried doing this while iterating but I am getting the error "vector iterators incompatible".

```
vector<Orb>::iterator i = orbsList.begin();

    while(i != orbsList.end()) {
        bool isActive = (*i).active;

        if(!isActive) {
            orbsList.erase(i++);
        }
        else {
            // do something with *i
            ++i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector

Answer (score 77):

The most readable way I've done this in the past is to use `std::vector::erase` combined with `std::remove_if`.  In the example below, I use this combination to remove any number less than 10 from a vector.

(**For non-c++0x, you can just replace the lambda below with your own predicate:**)

```
// a list of ints
int myInts[] = {1, 7, 8, 4, 5, 10, 15, 22, 50. 29};
std::vector v(myInts, myInts + sizeof(myInts) / sizeof(int));

// get rid of anything < 10
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                       [](int i) { return i < 10; }), v.end());
```

Comment: While elegant in the simple case, I'm dubious of its effectiveness in the real world. This wouldn't even work at all with a dynamic size vector.

Comment: "This wouldn't even work at all with a dynamic size vector." Why not?

Comment: While the `std::remove_if` lambda looks nice, but if I only want to delete exactly one element that matches the condition, it still goes through each element to the end. Therefore, I prefer manual iteration so I can break from the loop any time.

Answer (score 70):

I agree with wilx's answer. Here is an implementation:

```
// curFiles is: vector < string > curFiles;

vector< string >::iterator it = curFiles.begin();

while(it != curFiles.end()) {

    if(aConditionIsMet) {

        it = curFiles.erase(it);
    }
    else ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do that but you will have to reshuffle your `while()` a bit, I think. The `erase()` function returns an iterator to the element next after the erased one: `iterator erase(iterator position);`. Quoting from the standard from 23.1.1/7:

> The iterator returned from a.erase(q)
>   points to the element immediately
>   following q prior to the element being
>   erased. If no such element exists,
>   a.end() is returned.

Though maybe you should be using the [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) instead.

Comment: Also, to downsize the vector(as it seems to what the OP wants to do) the swap trick can be used. Details here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector

Comment: It might be enough to say `i=orbsList.erase(i)` instead of `orbsList.erase(i++)`

Answer (score 9):

`erase` returns a pointer to the next iterator value (same as Vassilis):

```
vector <cMyClass>::iterator mit
for(mit = myVec.begin(); mit != myVec.end(); )
{   if(condition)
        mit = myVec.erase(mit);
    else
        mit++;
}
```

Comment: access the value at the iterator position using `*mit`

Answer (score 4):

If someone need working on indexes

```
vector<int> vector;
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)vector.push_back(i);

int size = vector.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    assert(i > -1 && i < (int)vector.size());
    if(vector[i] % 3 == 0)
    {
        printf("Removing %d, %d\n",vector[i],i);
        vector.erase(vector.begin() + i);
    }

    if (size != (int)vector.size())
    {
        --i;
        size = vector.size();
        printf("Go back %d\n",size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just size-- i-- next to erase?

Comment: @user1122069 my good practices forbids such things, a lot of people do not understand difference between `--i` nad `i--`

Answer (score 1):

As they said, vector's iterators get invalidated on `vector::erase()` no matter which form of iterator increment you use. Use an integer index instead.

Comment: Using the return value of erase you get a valid iterator back. So it's only necessary to assign the returned value to the iterator -- no performance issue here.

Comment: @harper: Actually, there's a big performance issue here; erasing an item from the middle of a vector requires all the rest of them to be moved down, which involves O(N) constructor and destructor calls each time.

Comment: And the use of an index has what befinit? How is the erasing performance increased? I just annotated the statement "iterators get invalidated .. no matter which form"...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a `std::list` instead of a `std::vector` for your data structure. It is safer (less bug prone) to use when combining erasure with iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Removing items from the middle of a vector will invalidate all iterators to that vector, so you cannot do this (**update**: without resorting to Wilx's suggestion).

Also, if you're worried about performance, erasing items from the middle of a vector is a bad idea anyway.  Perhaps you want to use an `std::list`?

Comment: I know its a little late but you might wanna read this. Its contrary to what most people would expect but it comes from the creator of C++ http://bulldozer00.com/2012/02/09/vectors-and-lists/