# operator() from virtual class not recognized by remove_if

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have vector of objects and a vector of criteria to filter by. Inspired by Moo-Juice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713131/removing-item-from-vector-while-iterating), I wrote such a code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Token {

  char code;
   int val;

  Token(char c,int a) : code(c),val(a) {}
};

class FilterBase {
public:
  virtual bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Token> p) =0;
};

class ByCode : public FilterBase {
public:
  ByCode( char c) : code_(c) {}

  virtual bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Token> p) {
    return code_ == p->code;
  }

private:
  unsigned char code_;
};


int main() {

  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FilterBase>> filters;
  filters.push_back(std::make_shared<ByCode>('A'));
  filters.push_back(std::make_shared<ByCode>('B'));

  std::shared_ptr<Token> p = std::make_shared<Token>('M', 20);
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Token>> tokens;
  tokens.push_back(p);
  filters[0]->operator ()(p);

  for (const std::shared_ptr<FilterBase> fi : filters) {
    tokens.erase(std::remove_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), *fi), tokens.end());
  }
}
```

But unfortunately it does not compile, because **parameter type 'FilterBase' is an abstract class**. Well I know it is, I just thoght the *virtual* keyword would make it working...

Comment: A safety tip: if you declare any method as virtual, you should make the destructor virtual.

Comment: Try `std::ref( *fi )` instead of `*fi`.  `remove_if` takes its functor by-value, which causes slicing, which kills your program.  `std::reference_wrapper` seems to have an `operator()` overload to solve your problem, but I have not tested this solution yet.

Comment: `std::ref(*fi)` still gives abstract class cant be instanciated (on msvc10, had to replace rangebased for though)

Comment: @Yakk: Write that as an answer :)

Comment: @Bgie: I don't know why that is happening, it should not, and it probably indicates an issue with the implementation (VS, library)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I would, if I had any reason to think that MSVC would work right with this strange corner case.  So I embellished the answer with custom code to handle broken stdlib implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
tokens.erase(std::remove_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), *fi), tokens.end());
```

with:

```
tokens.erase(std::remove_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), std::ref(*fi)), tokens.end());
```

`remove_if` takes its functor by-value, which causes your `*fi` to be sliced into an instance of the base class, which has a pure `virtual` object.  Things go poorly.

`std::ref` has an overloaded `operator()` which should invoke the `virtual operator()` of `*fi` if MSVC didn't screw things up (for example, if it invokes the operator the wrong way).

If this fails, you can write your own adapter:

```
template<typename T>
struct callable_by_ref {
  T* t;
  template<typename... Args>
  auto operator(Args&&...args) const ->
  decltype( std::declval<T&>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...) )
  {
    return (*t)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
template<typename T>
callable_by_ref< typename std::remove_reference<T>::type >
call_by_ref( T&& t ) {
  return {&t};
}
```

which should solve your problem even if `std::ref` does not.

```
tokens.erase(std::remove_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), call_by_ref(*fi)), tokens.end());
```

What I am doing:

The `callable_by_ref` is basically a quick perfect forwarder with a half-functional `std::reference_wrapper` implementation on top of it.  `call_by_ref` does type deduction for you to create such an object.