# std::remove_if usage in C++98

Tags: c++, vector, c++98

I was looking for a smart way of erasing some elements in a vector while iterating, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713131/removing-item-from-vector-while-iterating).

Of course, it won't work for me, since C++98 doesn't have lambdas. Looked for remove_if info and found [this at cppreferenc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/?kw=remove_if)e. So this is how my code looks:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool isOutageValid(const Outage& outage){
    return outage.getEndTime() >= 0;
}

std::vector<Outage> outages;
// Some stuff to fill the vector

outages.erase(std::remove_if(outages.begin(), outages.end(), isOutageValid));

for(vector<Outage>::iterator o=outages.begin(); o!=outages.end(); o++){
    std::cout << o->getStartTime() << " " << o->getEndTime() << std::endl;
}
```

I am debugging with 4 Outages into a vector, where I know the first is invalid and the rest of them valid. After executing the erase, the vector size is 3, so it looks ok. But if I iterate with the `for` loop to inspect the 3 Outages into the vector, the second one has been erased instead of the first.

I even debugged the isOutageValid method, and it is the first the only one who is returning false. Is there any mistake I'm missing?

Comment: you meant  outages.begin(), right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
outages.erase(std::remove_if(outages.begin, outages.end(), isNotOutageValid), outages.end());
```

Currently, you partition outages not valid first, valid last (in other words, your predicate is inverted).
And then remove the fist valid element (instead of a range).

Comment: +1 I have been bitten more than once by leaving out the second `, outages.end()`...

Answer (score 4):

1.You forgot to specify the second argument of `erase`, which is the end of the range which is erased:

```
outages.erase(std::remove_if(outages.begin, outages.end(), isOutageValid), outages.end());
```

2.The condition is invalid, you should negate it:

```
 #include <functional>

 outages.erase(std::remove_if(outages.begin, outages.end(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun(&isOutageValid))), outages.end());
```

Comment: +1 I have been bitten more than once by leaving out the second `, outages.end()`...