# Adding and removing large amounts of data with std::vector

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to downsize std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector)

It seems that `std::vector` will not release memory even I call `pop_back()`, `clear()` or `resize()`.

Is there any good way to deal with this? For example, in the following code:

```
#include<vector>
　　
using namespace std;
　　
int main(){
  int i, j;
  vector<int> v[10000];
  for( i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++ ){
    for( j=0 ; j<100000000 ; j++ ){
      v[i].push_back(j);
    }
    while(v[i].size()>0){
      v[i].pop_back();
    }
    v[i].resize(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The vector will not release any memory until it finished.

Comment: It's worth noting that in C++0x, you can do `v.shrink_to_fit()`.

Comment: Sorry for Duplicated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` grows but never shrinks. The reason is that growing is expensive, so if you shrink and then grow back it's a waste of performance.

If you really want to shrink a large vector use the swap idiom:

```
std::vector<T> vec;
// push push push ...
std::vector<T>(vec).swap(vec);
```

This doesn't guarantee the new size of `vec` is exactly the sum of sizes of its elements, but it should be something close. Also, C++0x's `std::vector` will have a `shrink_to_fit()` member that will do roughly that.

Comment: `std::vector<T>(vec)` is a temporary that cannot bind to the parameter of `swap()`, a non-const reference. Reverse it: `std::vector<T>(vec).swap(vec)`.

Comment: Ah yes, noticed, I was just doing that. :p