# Vector capacity and reserve

Tags: c++, stl, memory-leaks, vector

Consider the following code snippet:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(100);
v.insert(v.end(), 100, 5);

v.erase(v.begin(), v.end());

std::cout << v.capacity << std::endl;
```

This prints out `100`. Does it mean that vector still holds the 100 memory locations? Is it required to call `reserve(0)` after calling `erase(begin,end)` on a vector, to relinquish all space held by the vector?

Comment: Why did you tag this question `memory-leaks`? Just because the vector holds some memory reserved, doesn't mean that this memory has leaked.

Comment: @Space: If it holds it for ever, even though you never reference it again, then surely that's a memory leak by definition?

Comment: because, i thought it is somehow related to memory leaks. if memory is not freed, it results in to memory leak.

Comment: @TonyK: A memory leak is memory that you cannot release anymore, because you don't have a pointer to it anymore. In this case, the vector manages it's memory, you just have to manage the lifetime of the vector correctly.

Comment: @Space: Yes, OK. If you really couldn't free up the memory during the vector's lifetime, then I would stand by my comment; but you can (as others have pointed out) by assigning it to an empty vector.

Comment: @BjörnPollex "_A memory leak is memory that you cannot release anymore_" No.

Comment: @curiousguy: I agree that that definition is incorrect, but your comment really is not very helpful, especially for readers who don't know what memory leaks are. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @BjörnPollex There is a memory leak whenever memory should be freed and is not and cannot be. Nothing more complicated or deep or formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the (in)famous swap trick:

```
vector<T>().swap(myVector);
```

See here for backgrounder

[How to downsize std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `vector<T>().swap(myvector)`?

Comment: @Azodious: you can read the backgrounder; It is commonly though of as a weak spot in the STL interface (you need a 'trick' to get memory allocation under control), much like the `std::endl` surprising effects and several other issues with iostream (notably performance)

Comment: @Shadow2531: you make me doubt my code; what _would_ be the difference? Afaict a swap is a swap. [Oh no: now I made that a 'great comment' by accident. Ah well]

Comment: @sehe: because the one way compiled for me and the other way did not.

Comment: @Azodious: Infamous because it is not intuitively obvious to a beginner. Code should be intuitive this is not.

Comment: @Shadow2531: uh... you're right of course; compiler doesn't like a temp bound to a non-const reference parameter; Making it a real proper lvalue would fix that, but it is one extra line of code :). **Fixed** ty

Answer (score 5):

If the capacity is 100, then the `vector` has space allocated for 100 elements. `reserve(0)` is a no-op, because `reserve` won't shrink the capacity.

`reserve(n)` will *try* to grow the allocation to enough space for *at least* `n` elements. There's no guarantee that it will succeed, it won't report failure and it may overallocate.

Don't call `reserve` unless you've measured your code with and without it and found it makes a significant difference. All other use of `reserve` is premature optimization.

Comment: `reserve(0)` isn't allowed to reduce the capacity (see 23.2.4.2/2). If you need to reduce the capacity (and generally you don't), you can copy the vector and then swap it with the original.

Comment: Ok. that's helpful. but how to make capacity equal to zero? because i'm sure that vector will be no more used after that.

Comment: @Alan: thanks, updated. @Azodious: if the vector is no longer needed, let it go out of scope.

Comment: @Azodious: If the vector was dynamically allocated, `delete` it. Otherwise just assign it an empty vector: `my_vector = std::vector<some_type>();`.

Comment: @larsmans: that method which has this vector, does some heavy calculations after all values are erased from this vector. so before those calculations start, i want to free the memory held by vector.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: but it won't free the memory until method returns.

Comment: @Azodious: You can always wrap the part of your method that uses the vector in a block (`{}`). At the end of the block, the vector goes out of scope and the memory will be released.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: yup, just after posting comment it clicked to mind but one more question. is it good to have these blocks? readeabilty-wise or is it a good programmng practice?

Comment: @Azodious: I do it very rarely. Most of the times it is an indicator that you should wrap some part of your code into a separate function.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: `my_vector = std::vector<some_type>();` is (as far as I know) not guaranteed to shrink the `vector`.  I think pre-C++11, `swap` is the only way to _guarantee_ that a `vector` shrinks.

Comment: @AlanStokes: For C++11, the relevant section is `§23.3.6.3/2`  `...Reallocation happens at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of reserve()...`  Though I've heard GCC violates this rule for `reserve(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a reminder, C++0x/11 added the `shrink_to_fit` convenience function to the STL container, which is already available in VS2010, so you're lucky if you're coding on Windows (with VS). :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the vector still holds 100 locations. `reserve` is only used to increase the size and isn't able to shrink it. A `reserve(0);` call would have no effect at all. In C++1x I believe there will be a `shrink_to_fit` call that you're interested in.

In the current standard, you have to use the swap trick to release storage allocated by a vector, but before you do, carefully consider if you really *want* to do that. If you add elements back to the vector later again you'll just reallocate. Unless you're on an embedded system just let vector manage its own memory.

Swap trick: Use `vector<T>().swap(myvector);` to release the storage of a vector.