# Recycling an unused vector

Tags: c++, vector

I've defined a vector in my program as follows:

```
vector<bool> isPrime (limit + 1, false);
```

where limit is an `int`. Later on in the program, I want to recycle the vector, keeping the name but reducing the size and populating all elements with `false`.

I've tried using

```
vector<bool> isPrime (otherLimit + 1, false);
```

in the same way one would redefine an `int`, `char` or `string`, but that returns an error, and since I didn't instantiate it with the `new` operator, I can't `delete` the old one. I've been able to manually resize it and and convert each element to false using a `for` loop, but that seems rather clunky to me.

Is there an easier way to recycle a vector? My desire is to keep the name the same throughout for readability purposes.

Comment: [See "reducing the size of a vector"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector).

Comment: And just to be pedantic: avoid std::vector<bool> (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B)#vector.3Cbool.3E_specialization)

Comment: why should he avoid it? although it is an unfortunate name for the functionality provided, there is no reason to avoid the functionality itself when you need it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: "avoid" is perhaps a bit strong. It doesn't meet the standard container requirements, which can cause subtle problems if you try to use it in generic code; but I don't see anything wrong with code that specifically uses (and understands) `vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either

```
isPrime = vector<bool>(otherLimit + 1, false)
```

or use it's members `clear` and `resize`:

```
isPrime.clear();
isPrime.resize(otherLimit + 1, false);
```

Comment: Another alternative: `isPrime.assign(otherLimit + 1, false);`

Comment: `clear` + `resize` will not actually yield back the memory, the common idiom would be something in the lines of `isPrime.swap( std::vector<bool>(otherLimit+1,false) );` for a *shrink-to-fit* operation that also resets everything to false.

Comment: Darn... I made a mistake above and cannot edit now... the `swap` should be reversed: `std::vector<bool>(otherLimit+1,false).swap(isPrime)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the copy assignment operator, and if you wish to reduce the space consumption you can use the member function shrink_to_fit():

```
isPrime = vector<bool>(otherLimit+1, false);
isPrime.shrink_to_fit()
```

Or if you're using C++0x, the move assignment operator:

```
isPrime = std::move(vector<bool>(otherLimit+1, false));
```

EDIT: As David pointed out, the compiler will identify the temporary as an rvalue and use rvalue references anyway, so the `std::move` is unnecessary, the following will be sufficient (and conveniently compatible with both C++03 and C++0x compilers, although move assignment will only be invoked in C++0x):

```
isPrime = vector<bool>(otherLimit+1, false);
```

These will both resize your vector and set all elements to false, but if you have access to it, using the move assignment operator will be more efficient.

Also, if you are using a C++03-only compiler, then using Davids `.swap()` idiom would be more efficient than a copy-assignment in this case.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: In response to David's post: http://ideone.com/wB77w

Comment: Already commented in the comment you added to my answer, but it also belongs here. Both pieces of code in this answer are *move-assignment*, when the right hand side is a temporary the compiler will *move* rather than *copy*. For it to be a *copy* assignment you need a non-temporary: `std::vector<bool> tmp(otherLimit+1,false); isPrime = tmp;` If you check that modification you will note that it does not return the allocated memory back.

Comment: Changed example, and replied to your comment. Thanks :)

Comment: The changed first example is still *move*, with the addition of a `shrink_to_fit` call, but it is not *copy*. Note that the `shrink_to_fit` is also a C++0x only feature, so both examples are C++0x. `shrink_to_fit()` has been simulated in C++03 for ages with the copy-and-swap idiom... `std::vector<bool>( isPrime.begin(), isPrime.end() ).swap( isPrime );`, but if you are going that path, you might as well, avoid the previous operation and just call `swap` on the temporary.

Comment: @David with the first example I was assuming a C++03 compiler, but yeah, I did add that your copy-and-swap idiom would be more efficient.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is C++0x, a C++03 compiler will fail in that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the vector using assignment, just as you’d do for `int` etc.

Alternatively, you can use the `resize` method.

Finally, I’d advise against all these approaches: **do not recycle variable names**. Use variables for one purpose only. Use a new name for a new variable.

Think of a variable name as identifying exactly one entity. The variable name binds the entity to the current scope (and thus, to existence). To create a new entity, always create a new variable name, or a new scope.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of answers suggesting assignment as in:

```
isPrime = std::vector<bool>(otherLimit+1,false);
```

While that solution will work, it might not be exactly what you want. I would suggest that you use the *swap-to-resize* trick:

```
std::vector<bool>(otherLimit+1,false).swap( isPrime );
```

The advantage is that the memory will *shrink-to-fit* `otherLimit+1` elements, and they will be set to `false` only once. In the assignment case, first `otherLimit+1` elements are created and set to `false` on the right hand side, and then those values are copied over the left hand side `isPrime` vector... (I don't remember off the top of my head if the operation will *shrink* the vector, but I doubt so, and that means that the `capacity()` of `isPrime` would be `std::max( limit+1, otherLimit+1 )`)

Comment: Move and copy assignments do seem to change capacity() too: http://ideone.com/wB77w :) Moreover; as far as I'm aware, a move constructor will be the most efficient too.

Comment: @Shaktal: If you are using a compiler with C++0x support, yes, *move* will be more efficient in most cases (it will avoid the allocation of the elements), but in C++03, `swap` of a temporary is more efficient than *copy*

Comment: @Shaktal: I have just looked at the example you provide in the ideone link. The example is wrong in that what you have labeled as *copy-assignment* is in fact *move-assignment*. Whenever a class has both *copy* and *move* capabilities and the argument is a temporary it will *move* rather than copy. *Copy* does not reset the capacity (you can check that by creating a named variable and using assignment with the rhs being a non-rvalue expression.

Comment: Ahh; yes, I forgot that was the case; I got confused because I thought the compiler preferred to wrongly bind it to an lvalue in certain cases (I thought these was one of them). You are indeed correct, my apologies. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the assignment (=) operator instead of the constructor:

```
isPrime = std::vector <bool> (otherLimit + 1, false)
```

Comment: The English word is “assignment operator”, not “affectation operator”.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector<..>::resize(..)` to resize it and `std::fill(..)` to set a specific value to all elements.