# C++ : Reduce reserved space with std::vector::reserve

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to downsize std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector)

According to cppreference, in std::vector::reserve(size_t n), n is "Minimum amount desired as capacity of allocated storage.". My question is : how to avoid any reallocation knowing only a maximum ?

As an example, let's say that I have a list of integers, but I don't know the size of this list (for example this list come from the reading of a file). But I know that the maximum size of this list is 1000. Let's say that the real size of the list is 800.

Currently, I use a std::reserve(1000), and then a loop of push_back(). Using reserve I prevent any reallocation. But how to free the extra space at the end of the push_backs ? (in the case of the example, how to release the 1000-800=200 extra space ?)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()`

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(1000);
for(int i=0;i<800;++i)
    v.push_back(10);

v.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: Which requires C++11 support. And isn't guaranteed to shrink anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, the standard says it's a non-binding request and "Note: The request is non-binding to allow latitude for implementation-specific optimizations." An example of where a quality implementation may choose not to adjust the capacity is when the current capacity is already low enough that the container is taking advantage of something like a small string optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to create a new vector at the correct size and swap the two vectors' contents. Fortunately, in STL that's a one-liner  Here's examples: [How to downsize std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector)

Comment: So… it's a duplicate question.