# why swap (this trick) shrink the capacity of vector?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

If I want to shrink the capacity of a vector, a binding way, also the old way to do it is :

```
std::vector<T>(v).swap(v);
```

Why? Why capacity is not also simply copied as well? Is it **guaranteed** in standard that copy initialization will construct a vector with the capacity that is lesser than the vector being copied? I tend to think it is just implementation specified.

(In standard, vector's specialization of `swap` will swap the element and capacity and that's **guaranteed**. But I can't find any guarantee about capacity for copy initialization. Please cite the standard if possible, Thank!)

Link to similar question : [What is the value of the capacity of std::vector when the copy constructor is used?](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/FbZwa0aViPc)

Comment: I am unable to locate anything that specifies what the initial capacity of the vector must be, either. "The old way" must be relying on implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253157/how-to-downsize-stdvector

Comment: Note that `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` isn't guaranteed to shrink either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love questions that make me re-evaluate what I thought to be true. Thank you!

Firstly, I had thought "capacity" was something that all containers have. Turns out that was my first mistake. It's just for `std::vector` and `std::string` (and `std::string_view`).

Now, looking at the expression you specified:

```
std::vector<T>(v).swap(v);
```

On one hand, we've got `std::vector<T>(v)`, which is making a copy of `v`, and on the other hand we have a swap of `v` (presumably, an `std::vector<T>`) with that copy.

Let's look at each step.

### Copy Constructor

Because `std::vector` is a container, it has to fulfill the requirements of a "container". This is where its copy constructor comes from. The copy constructor for `std::vector` is defined in the container.requirements section in [table 64](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements), in the row with the Expression `X(a)`. That row also specifies that the complexity must be linear. It also says that the post-condition of the copy "*Ensures*: `a == X(a)`".

To determine what "`a == X(a)`" means, we look further down in that [same table](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements), and see that:

> == is an equivalence relation. `equal(​a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end())`

If we take all the above together, it gives us a pretty good approximation of what the job of the copy constructor is: Populate an `std::vector` with equivalent values from another `std::vector`, in the same order.

But to be pedantic, there's no requirement about how much memory is allocated, or rather, how many times the allocated is called upon, other than enough to satisfy `std::vector<T>(v) == v`.

That being said, I'd be surprised if any implementer would allocate more than the minimum required. In C++ we like performance, and not paying for what we don't use. So unless there's a really good reason for the capacity to be greater, the capacity of the copied vector will be exactly the number of elements copied to it. Thus, it's **implementation specific**.

### Swap

In the [same table](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements), the row with the Expression `a.swap(b)` refers to "Note A". That note says:

> Those entries marked “(Note A)” [...] have constant complexity for [...] standard containers.

Also in container.requirements [21.2.1.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#general-9) there's the requirement that swap not invalidate any iterators:

> The expression a.swap(b), for containers a and b of a standard container type [...] shall exchange the values of a and b without invoking any move, copy, or swap operations on the individual container elements. [...] Every iterator referring to an element in one container before the swap shall refer to the same element in the other container after the swap. It is unspecified whether an iterator with value a.end() before the swap will have value b.end() after the swap.

This is very interesting and Good Stuff! Nobody likes having iterators invalidated, after all. (Compare with `shrink_to_fit`, which may invalidate the iterators if it has to reallocate.)

It also shapes our understanding of `swap` for containers. Since there is no allowed move/copy/swap on elements, and the iterators remain valid, this heavily implies to the implementer that the destination of the `swap` will take over the memory from the source vector. (Yes, I know it seems obvious, but the standard takes great and wonderful pains to make sure that the obvious is obvious to everyone by spelling everything out.)

As you mentioned, `std::vector` has a specialization for `swap`, which also requires that the `capacity` be swapped. In particular, see "vector" section [21.3.11.3.12](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#capacity-12), where it says:

> Effects: Exchanges the contents and `capacity()` of `*this` with that of `x`.

Which means that the standard guarantees that the `capacity` of `std::vector<T>(v)` will be swapped into `v`, when you do:

```
std::vector<T>(v).swap(v);
```

TL;DR The capacity of the swap-destination **is mandated** to be the same as the source of the swap. However, since the capacity of a copy-constructed `std::vector` is **not explicitly mandated** by the standard to be any specific value, it is implementation specific.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. **It is not guaranteed to work at all.** It just happens to work.

But one could ask another question: **Why should a library programmer implement a copy constructor that allocates significantly more storage than needed?** There might be rounding issues or maybe some spare, but it is just unlikely that e.g. twice as much storage is allocated.

---

However, I strongly recommend to **prefer the new `shrink_to_fit` function**. Although it has no storage guarantee either, an implementation might use an optimized allocation function that avoids to copy the entire elements (e.g. based on `realloc`). Whether the resulting memory fragmentation causes more harm than good is another question. But it should be left to the implementation to decide.

Comment: *"Why should a library programmer implement a copy constructor that allocates significantly more storage than needed?"*: We may ask similar question on the other hand: Why copy constructor won't do a "true" copy ? So previous `reserve` can be used by both copies (for some kind of "prefix" vectors). `vector` interface is poor about `capacity` :-/